# Records with different fields modelling same logical type

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

In my Haskell program I need to load a record from an API service in various ways. There's a `loadSmall :: IO Small` action which loads only some fields of those available. A `loadBig :: IO Big` action loads more fields. Perhaps there will need to be more "levels" of loading in the future.

For simplicity, let's assume that `Big` will always contain everything that `Small` does.

I would like functions to be able to access these two "versions" of the type in a uniform way. I've read about **lenses** and thought that I might try to use them here, but I'm not at all committed to using lenses if there's a simpler way to do it.

This is what I've come up with:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Control.Lens

class HasSmall a where
    name :: Lens' a Text

class HasSmall a => HasBig a where
    email :: Lens' a Text

data Big = Big
    { _bigName :: Text
    , _bigEmail :: Text
    -- ...possibly many more fields
    }
    deriving Show

makeLenses ''Big

instance HasSmall Big where
    name = bigName

instance HasBig Big where
    email = bigEmail

data Small = Small
    { _smallName :: Text
    -- ...probably at least a few fields more
    }
    deriving Show

makeLenses ''Small

instance HasSmall Small where
    name = smallName

-- Function that uses name
useName :: HasSmall a => a -> Text
useName s = "Hello " <> (s ^. name)
```

This does seem like a lot of boilerplate, since every new field has to be written in at least three places now.

Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: The TH machinery of *lens* includes [`makeFields`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19/docs/Control-Lens-TH.html#v:makeFields), which generates classes that abstract in a different direction (that is, one class per field). That is probably enough if all you need is uniform field access across your representations.

Comment: Thanks, that does look like a good option. I'm a bit surprised that makeFields doesn't seem to verify that the fields have the same type. I can change bigName to Int and the program still compiles. It would perhaps be slightly nicer if HasName could could fix the type of name to be Text, so that the type signatures of all consuming functions don't need to point out that name :: Text. I don't immediately see such an option in the lens documentation.

Answer (score 4):

If `Big`should contain everything that's also contained in `Small`, it may be viable to make `Small` a field of `Big`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
module Main where

class HasSmall a where
    accessSmall :: (Small -> b) -> (a -> b)

data Small = Small
    { name :: String
    , address :: String
    -- ...probably at least a few fields more
    }
    deriving Show

instance HasSmall Small where
    accessSmall = id

data Big = Big
    { small :: Small
    , email :: String
    -- ...possibly many more fields
    }
    deriving Show

instance HasSmall Big where
    accessSmall f = f . small

exampleSmall :: Small
exampleSmall = Small { name = "small name", address = "small address"}

exampleBig :: Big
exampleBig = Big { small = exampleSmall, email = "big email"}

printNameAndAddress :: HasSmall a => a -> IO ()
printNameAndAddress a = do
    putStrLn $ accessSmall name a
    putStrLn $ accessSmall address a

main :: IO ()
main = do
    printNameAndAddress exampleBig
    printNameAndAddress exampleSmall
```

This approach does not require lenses but can be easily modified to work with lenses, too, by altering the `HasSmall` class:

```
class HasSmall a where
    accessSmall :: Lens' Small b -> Lens' a b

instance HasSmall Small where
    accessSmall = id

instance HasSmall Big where
    accessSmall = (.) small
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as [`Control.Lens.TH`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19/docs/Control-Lens-TH.html) goes, the tool closest to what you want is `makeClassy`:

```
data Small = Small
    { _name :: Text
    -- ...probably at least a few fields more
    }
    deriving Show

makeClassy ''Small

data Big = Big
    { _bigSmall :: Small
    , _bigEmail :: Text
    -- ...possibly many more fields
    }
    deriving Show

makeClassy ''Big  -- As far as this demo goes, not really necessary.

instance HasSmall Big where
    small = bigSmall
```

This approach requires you to have a `Small` field in `Big`, so that access to the  fields within `Small` can be routed through the generated `HasSmall` class:

```
GHCi> :info HasSmall
class HasSmall c where
  small :: Lens' c Small
  name :: Lens' c Text
  {-# MINIMAL small #-}
    -- Defined at Test.hs:16:1
instance HasSmall Small -- Defined at Test.hs:16:1
instance HasSmall Big -- Defined at Test.hs:27:10
GHCi> :set -XTypeApplications
GHCi> :t name @Big
name @Big :: Functor f => (Text -> f Text) -> Big -> f Big
```

A different approach would be abstracting over the fields through `makeFields`:

```
data Small = Small
    { _smallName :: Text
    -- ...probably at least a few fields more
    }
    deriving Show

makeFields ''Small

data Big = Big
    { _bigName :: Text
    , _bigEmail :: Text
    -- ...possibly many more fields
    }
    deriving Show

makeFields ''Big
```

```
GHCi> :info HasName
class HasName s a | s -> a where
  name :: Lens' s a
  {-# MINIMAL name #-}
    -- Defined at Test2.hs:16:1
instance HasName Small Text -- Defined at Test2.hs:16:1
instance HasName Big Text -- Defined at Test2.hs:25:1
GHCi> :t name @Big
name @Big :: Functor f => (Text -> f Text) -> Big -> f Big
```

One potential disadvantage of `makeFields` in this use case is that, as you have noticed, the machinery leaves it completely open which types can be given to the fields. (In contrast, the definition of `Small` in the `makeClassy` example indirectly specifies any `name` lenses will have targets of `Text` type.)